# Send message to a button method w/o pressing the button

Tags: ios

Apologies: I may be too tired to be working...

I want to send a message to a button w/o pressing the button.  The button has an instance method, defined in the view controller, and properly hooked up and working when the button itself is pressed. The method is "newPuzzle", intended to load a new puzzle when pressed.  But I also want to trigger this method during start up, so that a new puzzle is loaded and ready to go, during loadView.  So I want to say [?? newPuzzle] in loadView.  Am I just missing the proper receiver syntax, or is something more elaborate required to accomplish this?  Suggestions, keywords, concepts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the IBAction is in the form

```
( IBAction) newPuzzle:(id) sender
```

If it is then simply do this to call the function in code(viewWillAppear)

[self newPuzzle:nil]:

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what I needed, and I'm glad I asked as I don't think I would have come up with that!